# The best and efficient way to store 7 bits value in C*

Tags: cassandra

I'm going to store a 7 bits value in Cassandra and looking for the most efficient data structure for that. Could you please suggest what can be the best and efficient data type to store 7 bits value in C*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the value is a numeric, whole number you could use `TINYINT`, which is meant for storing 8-bit (signed) integers.

Information on this and other data types supported by Apache Cassandra® can be found in this doc: https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/stable/cassandra/cql/types.html